# How to create the initial database on deployment?

Tags: sql-server, deployment, web-deployment

If I have a Silverlight application, and I am publishing to my localhost IIS server with the web deploy option:

- Can my database be automatically created in SQL Server Express?
  I'm not talking about creating tables and columns etc, i'm talking about creating the actual database at the destination.
- How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you specify a database name in the connection string it will automatically be created if it does not exist.